# Ajax cache cannot be flushed even with CTRL+F5

Tags: php, ajax, caching, header

For some time I tried hard to find a way to cache my ajax data, finally I find one but it's a little bit too far, see my title...

I use only one PHP file named "test.php", some html and jquery within.

Some code omitted, because the most important part is that three **header('...')**.

You can't miss any of them otherwise the ajax data will not be cached, but once you get them all, the ajax data will not be flushed even with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> unless clearing the browser's cache.

I do not want to lose the benefit of cache, but when database updated ajax request still get 304(NOT MODIFIED).At least after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, let me get a response with 200(OK).

```
<?php
  ...
  $test = $_GET['test'];
  $query = "select * from `xx` where id = '$test'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $str .= $row['name'];
  }

  //I want ajax data to be cached for only one hour

  $cache_time = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',strtotime('+1 hour')).' GMT';

  header('Cache-Control:must-revalidation');
  header('Expires:'.$cache_time);
  header('Pragma:cache');

  exit($str);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('li').live('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          data:'test=' + test,
          dataType:"text",
          url:"test.php",
          success:function(text){
            alert(text);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your cached data will cache for an hour no matter what unless the cache is explicitly cleared. You can set some sort of indicator such as `&noCache=1` for example and adjust appropriately when you see this. Also this code is subject to SQL injection, I suggest you use mysqli and parameterize your query.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher.But I don't quite understand. I don't know when the dadabase will be updated, I just expect CTRL+F5 can ignore the browser's cache.

Comment: Updating the DB won't invalidate the cache. Try adding a random extra param to your URL.. EG: ?b=<epochtime> or somesuch.

Comment: Thank @ethrbunny,I changed my url to 'test.php?random='+Math.random().But in that way the ajax data seemed never cached.I don't want to lose the benefit of cache, but when I use CTRL+F5, I want the browser to ignore the cache.

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you're passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: Thanks,Charles.The links are very helpful.Although I knew my code contains that vulnerability (just wanna keep it short), your advice is still very useful to me.I am a newbie :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
header('Cache-Control:must-revalidate');
```

instead of meaningless

```
header('Cache-Control:must-revalidation');
```